# how to integrate slider control in bar chart application in ios

Tags: ios, charts, slider, bar-chart

Hi friends i am creating Bar chart application using core plot headers, and I want the bar chart change their values using slider control. So i create the slider. slider values are changed but my bar chart was not changed. I don't know how to integrate the slider value in bar chart. If anybody know please share me. I am fresher for this. My code is shown below:
my slider code:

```
-(void)updateSliderValueTo:(CGFloat)_value {

[sliderValue setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", _value]];  }
```

And my bar chart code is :

```
 - (id)init
{

self = [super init];

if(sliderValue == 0)
{

if (self) 
{
     //NSLog(@"sliderval :%d", sliderValue);
    // Setting up sample data here.
    sampleData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:500], 
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:1500], 
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:2500], 
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:3500], 
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:4500], 
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:5500],
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:6500],
                                                  nil];

    sampleProduct = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"", @"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E",@"F",@"G",nil];

    // Initialize the currency formatter to support negative with the default currency style.
    currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [currencyFormatter setNegativePrefix:@"-"];
    [currencyFormatter setNegativeSuffix:@""];
}
}

else if(sliderValue != 0)
 {
   if(self)
   {
 sampleData = sliderValue; 
sampleProduct = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"", @"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E",@"F",@"G",nil];

    // Initialize the currency formatter to support negative with the default currency style.
    currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [currencyFormatter setNegativePrefix:@"-"];
    [currencyFormatter setNegativeSuffix:@""];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

move that init code into a buildGraph method which you can then call from iinit AND from a new IBAction you need (one that is hooked up to the Slider)

so

```
- (IBAction)onSliderChange {
     [self buildGraphData:self.slider.doubleValue]; //make the array with the new values
     [self.graph reloadData]; //you need this so CorePlot updates the specified graph view];
}
```

Comment: the clue is that you dont do it in init but reload the graph